# how to fit image without stretching and maintain aspect ratio in div tag in html

Tags: html, css

My image size is 640*820.And I want to fit this image into screen of size 310*520.
While doing this maintain aspect ratio(without stretch).

```
<div class="abc" style="
    background: url("images/phone.png");
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    margin-left:10px;
    background-size: contain;
    top: 50px;">
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what you've tried? You might want to look into setting the img as th background on a div, then setting css `background-size:contain`

Comment: I recommend replacing the double-quotes in your `url` with the `&quot;` entity to avoid problems parsing your HTML's `style` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You could just state the width of the image and have the height auto

```
.div img {
   width: 310px;
   height: auto;
}
<div class="div">
  <img src="#" title="#">
</div>
```